# Kendo UI MVC - Grid Paging, Sorting, Refreshing not working with WebAPI binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I set the datasource to WebAPI binding, the HTTP GET is being invoked on the controller and it returns the correct data. The problem is that my Kendo Grid is not binding the data correctly, instead I get an empty grid as a result.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Accounts")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title("Account Name");
          columns.ForeignKey(c => c.Type, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["accountTypes"], "Id", "Name").Title("Account Type");
          columns.ForeignKey(c => c.Currency, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["currencyTypes"], "Id", "Name").Title("Account Currency");
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(210);
        })
        .Sortable(sortable =>
        {
          sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
          sortable.AllowUnsort(false);
        })
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5)
        )
        .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .WebApi()
          .Model(model =>
          {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Currency).DefaultValue(0).Editable(true);
            model.Field(p => p.Description).Editable(true);
            model.Field(p => p.Type).Editable(true);
          })
          .ServerOperation(true)
          .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "Accounts"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("Post", "Accounts"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Put", "Accounts", new { id = "{0}" }))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Accounts", new { id = "{0}" }))
        .PageSize(10)
    )
)
```

**Controller**

```
// GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public DataSourceResult Get([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return _context.Accounts.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        }
```

I always get an HTTP 200 OK as a result of the paging or sorting command, but the grid is empty afterwards. The URL generated by Kendo is:

> http://localhost:58829/Accounts/Get?sort=&page=1&pageSize=10&group=&filter=

Which actually returns JSON when I open it with a browser.

Comment: Have you tried converting the data being returned with `Json()`? i.e. `return Json(_context.Accounts.ToDataSourceResult(request));` and change your controller function to `public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)`..

Comment: @Sandman, It's giving the same results

Comment: What if, along with the above change to your controller, modify your grid `DataSource` as follows. Replace `WebApi()` with `Ajax()` and set `.ServerOperation(false)`. If this still doesn't fix it, consider updating your question with the structure of the data being returned from your controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are mixing two different ways to load the data. On the one hand you are passing the Model by param to the grid (this approach is used when ServerOperation = false) and on the other hand you are setting ServerOperation = true and specifying a read action.

The reason why the grid is empty in this case is probably because either the Model is empty.

Take a look at this demo example for a reference on how to implement the remote source databinding: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/remote-data-binding

Example View:[image]

Example controller:
[image]

Hope this helps KendoGrid is an awesome library but like many other libraries it could definitely use better exception handling and more user friendly exceptions :)   In my opinion the grid should have shown an exception in this case.

Comment: This documentation is incomplete... Same goes for ASP.NET Core: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/remote-data-binding

Comment: What do you mean? What are you looking to implement that's not there?

Comment: Your answer is coherent, I am mixing WebAPI binding for Post, Put, Delete actions and Ajax binding for the Get action which don't mix

Comment: You usually only need custom ajax binding in kendo if you want to override the sorting, filtering and grouping functionality of the grid. Is that what you are trying to do? I gathered from your question that you were looking to use the built-in grid functionality for those features but that the data was not showing did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: No, I think you understood correctly. I am not looking to override the Paging and Sorting functions. I'm trying to get the build-in features of Kendo UI with WebApi binding to work based on this documentation: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/webapi

Comment: I have had to do that probably dozens of times :P  so I can definitely help you with that. What's wrong with the link that I sent you initially? What problem are you facing when you use it?

Comment: The problem is that, I am using WebApi binding. So far, all my commands are working, except for the HTTP GET command which isn't

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in the original answer? (removing the Model that you are passing by param?)

Comment: Can you be more clear about what Model being passed where please.

Comment: I just edited my answer and posted new code that I used in one of my projects for the view and for the controller. It's an ASP.NET Core project so I had to use kendo's deferred method but other than that it should be the same for you.

Comment: @JFBeaulieu did that help?

Comment: no it didn't solve the problem. You are using `Ajax()` binding. My goal is to use `WebApi()` binding.

Comment: I missed that part did you take a look at this: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/webapi

Comment: And if you don't mind me asking why are you looking to use web api?

Comment: I have tried the Ajax approach, the `Read` command is doing a POST instead of a GET

Comment: OK I had to remove the [HttpGet] annotation so the read method could be reached. I'm getting the same result. Empty grid.

Comment: Using Ajax or WebApi?

Comment: Using Ajax. Is it the Dependencies that could be the problem??

Comment: No, that would throw a js exception. Did you use the code that I posted? And did you remove the Model that you were passing by parameter to the grid?

Comment: No I kept the model there. Why would I want to remove it?

Comment: Because you are using two data data sources you should either pass the Model that will populate the grid by parameter in which case server action should be set to false and you shouldn't have a read action OR you set the read action as your data source

Comment: It is now working! I had to keep passing the Model and set the ServerOperation to false, and removing the `Read` action. Let's have this in a detailed answer because this isn't documented anywhere!

Comment: Np! @JFBeaulieu happy to help

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this: when declaring the Kendo Grid and passing the Model as a parameter like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
```

You need to remove the `.Read()` action, and make sure to use `.ServerOperation(false)`. This works either with WebApi binding or Ajax binding:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .WebApi()    // also works with .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
          model.Id(p => p.Id);
        }
      )
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Create(create => create.Action("Post", "Invoices"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Put", "Invoices", new { id = "{0}" }))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Invoices", new { id = "{0}" }))
      .PageSize(10)
)
```

Also, the `DataSourceResult Get()` method can be removed.